# Determine whether a tmux window has been renamed

Tags: tmux

The behavior of a tmux window's name varies based on whether the window has been manually renamed. A window that has not been manually renamed actively refreshes to the name of whatever program is actively running (`bash`, `vi`, etc.), whereas a renamed window keeps its custom name even when the active program changes.

I would like to programmatically determine which behavior is being followed. In other words, I want to determine whether a window has been manually renamed. This would allow me to write scripts that say: "If the user has overridden the default window name, then respect the user's custom window name. Otherwise, override the default names in my fancy way."

Is this possible? I didn't see anything about it in the [list of tmux variables](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS).

Answer (score 4):

When you rename a window manually, tmux will turn automatic-rename off in the window options for that window:

```
$ tmux -Ltest -f/dev/null new -d
$ tmux -Ltest show -w
$ tmux -Ltest renamew foo
$ tmux -Ltest show -w
automatic-rename off
$
```

So you could check for that.

It may be better to just set automatic-rename-format to the format you want and let tmux worry about whether the user has renamed the window or not.